# Python Unicode Casting on Variable Bug

Tags: python, variables, unicode, casting

I've found out this weird python2 behavior related to unicode and variable:

```
>>> u"\u2730".encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'e29cb0'
```

This is the expected result I need, but I want to dynamically control the first part ("u\u2730")

```
>>> type(u"\u2027")
<type 'unicode'>
```

Good, so the first part is casted as unicode. Now declaring a string variable and casting it to unicode:

```
>>> a='20'
>>> b='27'
>>> myvar='\u'+a+b.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(myvar)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print myvar
\u2027
```

It seems that now I can use the variable in my original code, right?

```
>>> myvar.encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'5c7532303237'
```

The results, as you can see, is not the original one. It seems that python is treating 'myvar' as string instead of unicode. Do I miss something?

Anyway, my final goal is to loop Unicode from \u0000 to \uFFFF, cast them as string and cast the string as HEX. Is there an easy way?

Comment: You are confusing the unicode escape sequence with an actual `\u`

Comment: Note that `\u` on its own isn't a valid unicode string, that doesn't make sense: `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape`. Also note that the `__repr__`esentation of `myvar` is `u'\\u2027'` (note the escapes), `print`ing (which uses the `__str__`ing form) isn't helpful here.

Comment: Using both u"\u2730" is the only way to obtain the information I need. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user2287463 again, you are confusing an escape-sequence with the character itself. It's like confusing `r"\n"` with an actual newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the Unicode escape sequence with an the `\u` characters. It's like confusing `r"\n"` (or `"\\n"`) with an *actual* newline. You want to <strike>use`codecs.raw_unicode_escape_decode`</strike> `decode` the `str` with `'unicode_escape'`:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> a='20'
>>> b='27'
>>> myvar='\u'+a+b.decode('utf-8')
>>> myvar
u'\\u2027'
>>> myvar.decode('unicode_escape')
(u'\u2027', 6)
>>> print(myvar.decode('unicode_escape')[0])
‧
```

Comment: `('\\u'+a+b).decode('unicode_escape')` is shorter.  Start with a byte string.

Answer (score 1):

`unichr()` in Python 2 or `chr()` in Python 3 are the ways to construct a character from a number.  `\uxxxx` escapes codes can only be typed directly in code.

Python 2:

```
>>> a='20'
>>> b='27'
>>> unichr(int(a+b,16))
u'\u2027'
```

Python 3:

```
>>> a='20'
>>> b='27'
>>> chr(int(a+b,16))
'‧'
```